# AJAX jQuery .click Element running function on load instead of click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, onclick

Maybe i'm just a jQuery noob, but I don't understand why when I set an elements .click event it runs when the element loads.

Code:

```
//Deal Cards button
$(".draw-cards").click(function(){
    var playerId = 1;
    var gameId = 20;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: './system/actions/draw.php',
        data: "playerId=" + playerId,
        success: function(data) {
            //Post to Player Card container
            $('#player-cards').html(data);
            //Resize Fonts
            fontSize();
            //For each loaded check if usable
            $( ".card" ).each(function() {
                var cardId = $(this).attr('id');
                comparePlayerCard(cardId, function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    if (data == 1){
                        $("#"+cardId+".card").css('box-shadow', '0px 0px 12px 6px #00ff40');
                        $("#"+cardId+".card").click(addCardToInventory(playerId, gameId, cardId)); // <---- PROBLEM CODE
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The function inside

```
$("#"+cardId+".card").click(addCardToInventory(playerId, gameId, cardId));
```

Is being run when the element loads through the AJAX, then it doesn't work when I click the element.  Not sure why.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `addCardToInventory(playerId, gameId, cardId)` will call the function directly instead of when clicked. Use anonymous function `$("#" + cardId + ".card").click(function () {
    addCardToInventory(playerId, gameId, cardId)
});`

Comment: Try calling your `function` in an `anonymous function` - `$("#"+cardId+".card").click(function(){
addCardToInventory(playerId, gameId, cardId)});`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao No, no. Anonoymous function within a loop is a **bad practice**.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev thanks for sharing.. but if it is the requirement of OP, to pass it as argument without modifying function then there is no other approach right?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Yeah, you are right. In this case, use anonymous function :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't pass function call this way.

It should be **an anonymous function**:

```
$("#"+cardId+".card").click(function() {
    functionaddCardToInventory(playerId, gameId, cardId);
});
```

It is usually the most suitable approach, but it is a bad practice to use anonymous functions within a loop.

Or it can be a **function without arguments**:

```
$("#" + cardId + ".card").click(functionaddCardToInventory);
```

In this case, you can describe your values as a global values or within `data` attributes:

HTML:

```
<div id="cardId" class="card" data-game-id="7" data-card-id="11"></div>
```

JS:

```
var playedId = 14;    

function functionaddCardToInventory()
{
    var cardId = $(this).data("card-id");
    var gameId = $(this).data("game-id");
    // and playerId is global
}

// Function without arguments can be passed this way
$("#" + cardId + ".card").click(functionaddCardToInventory);
```